# how to combine order_by and filter_by in sqlalchemy using flask

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I want to call a query by filter_by and order_by them by using a column of the filtered data. Pls tell how do I achieve so.

```
 current_blog_post_replies = current_blog_post_reply.filter_by(blog_reply = blog_post_id)
```

Now i want to order_by this query by a column called time. Pls tell how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing your table class is named  **CurrentBlogPostReply**.

**Use this query**

```
current_blog_post_replies = CurrentBlogPostReply.query.filter(CurrentBlogPostReply.blog_reply == blog_post_id).order_by(CurrentBlogPostReply.time).all()
```